# How can I activate an iPhone 5s locked to another person's iCloud account?

Tags: iphone

I bought a used iPhone 5s and unknowing to me it is locked to an iCloud account with a gmail address (p*****@gmail.com). I formatted the iPhone and upon activating it the iCloud prompt appears and frankly speaking I can't trace the old user of the phone. Please what can I do to activate it because i don't have a clue where the previous owner lives. Please help me because I used my savings to purchase the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but there isn't a way to remove the previous activation without the previous owners iCloud details. That would defeat the purpose of these anti-theft measures.

Apple provide instructions here on [how to remove the activation lock](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201441). You will need to contact the previous owner. Please speak to whoever you bought the iPhone from.